# How do I make VBA.Shell run a simple Python code?

Tags: python, excel, vba

Basically when I try to run a python code in excel, it just pops a cmd windows and doesn't run it at all.

The code I'm using is:

```vb
Sub RunPython()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim PythonExePath As String
    Dim PythonScriptPath As String

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExePath = """pythonpath"""
    PythonScriptPath = """scriptpath"""

    objShell.Run PythonExePath & PythonScriptPath
End Sub
```

I wrote pythonpath and scriptpath because I don't want to show the paths I'm using, it's confidential, but I was wondering if my syntax is wrong or there's another way to run this code that I'm not figuring out.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? If you get an error saying it cannot find the program, you may be missing a space between `PythonExePath` and `PythonScriptPath`. If that doesn't help, please make a [mcve] with a dummy script.

Comment: Robert, thank you so much for your answer and you're correct, I added the spaces you just mentioned and it actually work.